# com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'r.payload')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I couldn't find exactly why this error is coming. It doesn't look like coming from my code. I guess this is some issue with react native or some other dependency. Any help or pointers will be very helpful.

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'r.payload'), stack:
<unknown>@927:1701
<unknown>@927:1499
<unknown>@714:82
value@845:2846
updateComponent@174:5248
receiveComponent@174:4634
receiveComponent@164:578
_updateRenderedComponent@174:6485
_performComponentUpdate@174:6254
updateComponent@174:5531
receiveComponent@174:4634
receiveComponent@164:578
updateChildren@172:475
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@169:988
_updateChildren@169:1764
updateChildren@169:1652
receiveComponent@149:830
receiveComponent@164:578
_updateRenderedComponent@174:6485
_performComponentUpdate@174:6254
updateComponent@174:5531
receiveComponent@174:4634
receiveComponent@164:578
updateChildren@172:475
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@169:988
_updateChildren@169:1764
updateChildren@169:1652
receiveComponent@149:830
receiveComponent@164:578
updateChildren@172:475
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@169:988
_updateChildren@169:1764
updateChildren@169:1652
receiveComponent@149:830
receiveComponent@164:578
updateChildren@172:475
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@169:988
_updateChildren@169:1764
updateChildren@169:1652
receiveComponent@149:830
receiveComponent@164:578
_updateRenderedComponent@174:6485
_performComponentUpdate@174:6254
updateComponent@174:5531
receiveComponent@174:4634
receiveComponent@164:578
updateChildren@172:475
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@169:988
_updateChildren@169:1764
updateChildren@169:1652
receiveComponent@149:830
receiveComponent@164:578
_updateRenderedComponent@174:6485
_performComponentUpdate@174:6254
updateComponent@174:5531
receiveComponent@174:4634
receiveComponent@164:578
updateChildren@172:475
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@169:988
_updateChildren@169:1764
updateChildren@169:1652
receiveComponent@149:830
receiveComponent@164:578
_updateRenderedComponent@174:6485
_performComponentUpdate@174:6254
updateComponent@174:5531
receiveComponent@174:4634
receiveComponent@164:578
updateChildren@172:475
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@169:988
_updateChildren@169:1764
updateChildren@169:1652
receiveComponent@149:830
receiveComponent@164:578
_updateRenderedComponent@174:6485
_performComponentUpdate@174:6254
updateComponent@174:5531
receiveComponent@174:4634
receiveComponent@164:578
_updateRenderedComponent@174:6485
_performComponentUpdate@174:6254
updateComponent@174:5531
receiveComponent@174:4634
receiveComponent@164:578
_updateRenderedComponent@174:6485
_performComponentUpdate@174:6254
updateComponent@174:5531
performUpdateIfNecessary@174:4850
performUpdateIfNecessary@164:768
l@161:767
perform@168:503
perform@168:503
perform@161:1833
B@161:2005
closeAll@168:1142
perform@168:590
batchedUpdates@249:456
a@161:321
_receiveRootNodeIDEvent@151:819
receiveEvent@151:929
value@94:3762
<unknown>@94:1998
b@94:626
value@94:1970
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:95)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:79)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModule$JavaMethod.invoke(BaseJavaModule.java:322)
    at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```